# How to fix the nzType isn't a known property of 'i' in antd v11.4.0

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

How to fix the:

> can't bind to 'nzType' since it isn't a known property of 'i'?

here's the code

***index.component.html***

```
<nz-header>
  <i class="trigger" nz-icon [nzType]="isCollapsed ? 'menu-unfold' : 'menu-fold'" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"></i>
</nz-header>
```

***index.component.ts***

```
isCollapsed = false;
```

***index.module.ts***

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ShellComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NzLayoutModule,
    NzBreadCrumbModule,
    NzDropDownModule,
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import [`NzIconModule`](https://ng.ant.design/components/icon/en).

### Step 1: Dynamic importing via angular.json

> angular.json

```
{
  "assets": [
    {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "./node_modules/@ant-design/icons-angular/src/inline-svg/",
      "output": "/assets/"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Step 2: Add Icons in Lazy-loaded Modules

> index.module.ts

```js
import { NzIconModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/icon';
import {
  MenuFoldOutline,
  MenuUnfoldOutline
} from '@ant-design/icons-angular/icons';
import { IconDefinition } from '@ant-design/icons-angular';

const icons: IconDefinition[] = [MenuFoldOutline, MenuUnfoldOutline];

export class IndexModule {
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    NzIconModule.forChild(icons)
  ]
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a9e3ay)

Note:

1. How do I know a icon's corresponding module to import?

> Capital camel-case type & theme, i.e. alibaba => AlibabaOutline.

---

### Reference(s)

1. [Add Icons in Lazy-loaded Modules](https://ng.ant.design/components/icon/en#add-icons-in-lazy-loaded-modules)
2. [How do I know a icon's corresponding module to import?](https://ng.ant.design/components/icon/en#faq)